# Split(" ") 3 spaces returns 2 empty strings instead of 1?

Tags: javascript, split, concatenation

I am having trouble understanding the split method in which there is 3 spaces between 2 characters in a string. For example is if there is a string that looks like this "a   b" and I try to use JS's split function, it will return ['a','','','b'] instead of ['a','','b']. Why is this happening and **how do I achieve ['a','','b'] instead**?

```js
const threeSpaces = 'a   b'
console.log(threeSpaces.split(' '))
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: You have five characters in your string. You split and you get everything *between* the character you split with. So with `a<space1><space2><space3>b` you get `a`, then the content between `<space1>` and `<space2>` then the content between `<space2>` and `<space3>` then `b`.

Comment: `"a   b".split(/ +/)`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @VLAZ . However in this case, how do I get ['a',' ','b']? Is there any other method that can achieve this?

Comment: @SalmanA I have tried using / +/ but that just eliminated all the spaces. I need to get the space in the middle instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let threeSpaces = 'a      b';
threeSpaces = threeSpaces.replace(/\s\s+/g, '  ');
const result = threeSpaces.split(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: How does this work exactly? what does this regex mean? /\s\s+/g

Comment: @Squish it replaces any length of multiple spaces with only two spaces. It then splits by a single space.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex

```
/()\s+/
```

> If separator is a regular expression with capturing parentheses, then
> each time separator matches, the results (including any undefined
> results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output
> array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```js
const threeSpaces = 'a   b'

console.log(threeSpaces.split(/()\s+/))
```

Comment: Wow, I never realised that's how capturing groups work with splitting.